# How to determine whether a metric meets the Kerr-Schild form?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

A Kerr-Schild metric can be expressed as $$g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+\phi k_\mu k_\nu,$$ where
$\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is Minkowski metric, $\phi$ is a scalar function and $k_\mu$ is a (co)vector field which is null with respect to both the Minkowski and full metric, i.e. $g_{\mu\nu}k^\mu k^\nu=\eta_{\mu\nu}k^\mu k^\nu=0$. There are many solutions meet Kerr-Schild form, such as Schwarzschild solution, Kerr solution, pp-waves and so on. But it is difficult to determine whether a metric meets the Kerr-Schild form. Even for Schwarzschild solution, the Kerr-Schild form must be obtained through coordinate transformation in 4.2.1 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.08630). So is there a general way to determine whether a metric meets the Kerr-Schild form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A necessary condition for a metric of a vacuum solution to admit Kerr–Schild form is the existence of double *principal null direction*, so the spacetime must be algebraically special in the sense of [Petrov's classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrov_classification). This is proven in the paper

- Gürses, M., & Gürsey, F. (1975). Lorentz covariant treatment of the Kerr–Schild geometry. Journal of Mathematical Physics, 16(12), 2385-2390, [doi:10.1063/1.522480](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.522480).

---

A set of necessary and sufficient conditions  for the metric to be of Kerr–Schild type formulated in terms of Newman–Penrose spin coefficients could be found in a paper by Debever

- Debever, R. (1974). *Sur une classe d'espaces Lorentziens.* Bulletins de l'Académie Royale de Belgique, 60(1), 998-1011, [link with OA pdf](https://www.persee.fr/doc/barb_0001-4141_1974_num_60_1_60988).

**Abstract** (Google translated from French)

> We determine necessary and sufficient conditions for a Lorentzian manifold $(V_4,g)$ to have a metric $g$ equivalent to
> $$η + l ⊗ l$$ where $η$ is the Minkowskian metric and $l$ is a field of real isotropic vectors. The trajectories of $l$ are moreover geodesic, without distortion and with divergence for the metric $η$ and consequently for the metric $g$.
>
> Metrics of this type, solutions of vacuum equations have been studied by R. Kerr and A. Schild [$1$].

Comment: What is the case when the solutions contain cosmological constant ?  For example, can the Kerr-de Sitter solution be written in Kerr-Schild form with a Minkowskian base metric？