# Question on the transformation from Boyer-Lindquist to Kerr-Schild coordinates, for a modified Kerr metric

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, kerr-metric

From Kerr metric, we do know that there exist a function with the form of:

$$\Delta = r^2 - 2 M r + a^2 \tag{1}.$$

Following $[1]$, I did understand the coordinate transformation from Boyer-Lindquist (BL) to Kerr-Schild (KS) coordinates,  (BL$\to$ KS), for the Kerr spacetime:

$$
dt' = dt + \frac{2 M r}{r^2 - 2 M r + a^2} dr = dt + \frac{2 M r}{\Delta} dr , d\phi'=d\phi + \frac{a}{r^2 - 2 M r + a^2} dr = d\phi + \frac{a}{\Delta} dr. \tag{2}.
$$

Now, suposse we have a general version of $\Delta$ function, such as:

$$\Delta' = Kr^2 - 2 M r + a^2 + f(r) \tag{3}.$$

Where, $K$ is a constant. My question is:

> The tranformation (BL$\to$KS) would have its form precisely as:
> $$
> dt' = dt + \frac{2 M r}{\Delta'} dr , d\phi'= d\phi + \frac{a}{\Delta'} dr \tag{4}?
> $$

---

$[1]$ [Coordinate transform of Kerr metric to Kerr-Schild coordinates](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/786291/coordinate-transform-of-kerr-metric-to-kerr-schild-coordinates)

Comment: Not every metric admits KS form. Have you checked that yours does?

Comment: @A.V.S. No because I don't know how to perform this check. Nevertheless, what do you think? Do you think $(4)$ is a suitable form?

Comment: *I don't know how to perform this check* Have a look at references from [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/771845/180269) or maybe at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0203088).

Comment: … *what do you think*? This depends on what are you trying to accomplish. Does your metric represent some specific solution? Are you looking for  KS form with a curved seed metric?

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/772647/24093